Is it possible to send an array of FormData objects in an httpClient.post?
I have an Angular frontend app with a Java backend in which the user select a document and then saves it.
To do this, I've been sending a FormData object from the frontend to the backend with no issues.
Here's a snippet of what I currently have in the frontend that works to send the contents of a single file to the backend:
public postSaveDocument(entityType: DocumentEntityType, id: number, body: DocumentInputDto): Observable<Upload<UploadWithLockResultsDto>> {

    const url = `${DocumentationService.baseUrl}/${getUrlSegment(entityType)}/${id}/documents`;

     //Create a FormData object and set the values of the document
     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('documentId', this.documentId.toString());
     formData.append('title', this.title);
     formData.append('content', this.content, this.content.name);
    


    return this.httpClient.post(url, formData,
      {...DocumentationService.options, reportProgress: true, observe: 'events', responseType: 'json'})
      .pipe(upload<UploadWithLockResultsDto>());



}

And here's what I do in the backend that works to save that file:
@PostMapping("/{documentEntityType}/{entityId}/documents")
    public ResponseEntity<UploadWithLockResultsDto> saveDocument(
           @PathVariable("documentEntityType") DocumentEntityType documentEntityType,
           @PathVariable("entityId") Integer entityId,
           DocumentInputDto documentInputDto,
                                   ) throws AuthException, IOException {

           //Save the updates to the database
           var uploadWithLockResultsDto = documentService.documentUpdate(documentInputDto, authentication.getName(), authentication.getPrincipal());
           return handleUploadWithLockResults(uploadWithLockResultsDto);
   
}

And this works just fine to save a single document.
Now what I would like to do is allow the user to select more than one documents at a time, and save them in one fell swoop as they are sent to the back end.
So far no luck with this.
I've tried putting the data into an array of FormData objects in the front-end
public postSaveDocuments(entityType: DocumentEntityType, id: number, body: DocumentInputDto[]): Observable<Upload<UploadWithLockResultsDto>> {

    const formDataArray: any[] = [];
    body.forEach(documentInputDto => {

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('documentId', this.documentId.toString());
      formData.append('title', this.title);
      formData.append('content', this.content, this.content.name);
      formDataArray.push(formData);
    });

    return this.httpClient.post(url, formDataArray,
      {...DocumentationService.options, reportProgress: true, observe: 'events', responseType: 'json'})
      .pipe(upload<UploadWithLockResultsDto>());
}

And then I try to scoop it up in the backend as an array
@PostMapping("/{documentEntityType}/{entityId}/documents")
    public ResponseEntity<UploadWithLockResultsDto> saveDocument(
           @PathVariable("documentEntityType") DocumentEntityType documentEntityType,
           @PathVariable("entityId") Integer entityId,
           DocumentInputDto[] documentInputDtos,
                                   ) throws AuthException, IOException {

           //Save the docs to the database
           var uploadWithLockResultsDto = documentService.updateDocuments(documentInputDtos, authentication.getName(), authentication.getPrincipal());
           return handleUploadWithLockResults(uploadWithLockResultsDto);
   
}

Not surprisingly this doesn't work.  It never even gets to the backend.  And I realize that an array of FormData objects probably isn't meant to be sent from the frontend to the backend.
Can anyone point me in the right direction though as how to modify the call such that more than one FormData objects are sent from the front to the back?
Thanks much.

You should send a single formData and append each file like formData.append("file1", file1), formData.append("file2", file2) etc. You can use for loop for that and instead of file1 use documentId1, title1, etc.

You're on the right track, but sending multiple FormData objects in an array directly from the frontend to the backend is not going to work because the FormData object is meant to be sent as a single entity. Instead, you should send the documents as individual parts in a single FormData object using a multi-part form request.
Step 1: Frontend - Modify the FormData object to handle multiple files
To send multiple files, you can append each document's data to the same FormData object with unique keys for each document. This will allow you to send multiple documents in one HTTP request.
Updated frontend code:
public postSaveDocuments(entityType: DocumentEntityType, id: number, body: DocumentInputDto[]): Observable<Upload<UploadWithLockResultsDto>> {

    const url = `${DocumentationService.baseUrl}/${getUrlSegment(entityType)}/${id}/documents`;

    // Create a single FormData object for all documents
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Loop through the document DTOs and append each one
    body.forEach((documentInputDto, index) => {
      formData.append(`documents[${index}].documentId`, this.documentId.toString());
      formData.append(`documents[${index}].title`, this.title);
      formData.append(`documents[${index}].content`, this.content, this.content.name);
    });

    return this.httpClient.post(url, formData, {
      ...DocumentationService.options,
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
      responseType: 'json'
    }).pipe(upload<UploadWithLockResultsDto>());
}

Step 2: Backend - Handle the multi-part form data
In the backend, you need to handle the multiple files and their associated metadata. You can do this by accepting the data as a MultipartFile array or a custom DTO, depending on how you prefer to structure the request. Since you are sending metadata and files, you can use a combination of @RequestParam and @ModelAttribute annotations to bind the form data and file content.
Updated backend code:
@PostMapping("/{documentEntityType}/{entityId}/documents")
public ResponseEntity<UploadWithLockResultsDto> saveDocuments(
    @PathVariable("documentEntityType") DocumentEntityType documentEntityType,
    @PathVariable("entityId") Integer entityId,
    @RequestParam("documents") List<MultipartFile> documents,
    @RequestParam Map<String, String> documentMetadata) throws AuthException, IOException {

    // Parse metadata and files
    List<DocumentInputDto> documentInputDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < documents.size(); i++) {
        MultipartFile file = documents.get(i);
        String documentId = documentMetadata.get("documents[" + i + "].documentId");
        String title = documentMetadata.get("documents[" + i + "].title");

        DocumentInputDto documentInputDto = new DocumentInputDto();
        documentInputDto.setDocumentId(Long.parseLong(documentId));
        documentInputDto.setTitle(title);
        documentInputDto.setContent(file); // Assuming the DocumentInputDto has a 'content' field for the file

        documentInputDtos.add(documentInputDto);
    }

    // Save the documents to the database
    var uploadWithLockResultsDto = documentService.updateDocuments(documentInputDtos, authentication.getName(), authentication.getPrincipal());
    return handleUploadWithLockResults(uploadWithLockResultsDto);
}

Step 3: Update your DocumentInputDto
public class DocumentInputDto {
    private Long documentId;
    private String title;
    private MultipartFile content; // The file being uploaded
    
    // Getters and setters...`enter code here`
}


Thanks much for your help.
It is at least getting to the back end - and the documentMetadata is getting through just fine.
The one issue I'm still having is that the documents array is coming back null.
And yes - I do have a MultipartFile content member variable in my DocumentInputDto class.

The issue you're facing with the documents array coming back as null is likely because of how Spring handles form data and multipart file uploads. The problem could be that you're sending files and form data (like the metadata) under the same name (documents[]) in your request, but Spring may not be correctly mapping the MultipartFile parts to the List documents.
Let's walk through some adjustments you can make to ensure Spring correctly maps the file data and metadata to the proper fields.
Step 1: Update the Frontend Code
You are already sending the files with metadata in a single FormData object. The key issue is ensuring the correct structure of the request so that the backend can correctly identify both the files and the metadata. The files need to be sent with separate name fields for each document, and the metadata should follow the same naming convention.
Here’s the updated frontend code to append multiple documents correctly:
public postSaveDocuments(entityType: DocumentEntityType, id: number, body: DocumentInputDto[]): Observable<Upload<UploadWithLockResultsDto>> {
    const url = `${DocumentationService.baseUrl}/${getUrlSegment(entityType)}/${id}/documents`;

    // Create a single FormData object to handle multiple files and their metadata
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Loop through the document DTOs and append each one to the formData object
    body.forEach((documentInputDto, index) => {
        // Append metadata fields
        formData.append(`documents[${index}].documentId`, documentInputDto.documentId.toString());
        formData.append(`documents[${index}].title`, documentInputDto.title);

        // Append the file for this document
        formData.append(`documents[${index}].content`, documentInputDto.content, documentInputDto.content.name);
    });

    // Send the FormData as a POST request
    return this.httpClient.post(url, formData, {
        ...DocumentationService.options,
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
        responseType: 'json'
    }).pipe(upload<UploadWithLockResultsDto>());
}

Step 2: Update the Backend Code
Spring uses the @RequestParam to bind form data and file uploads. The key to solving this issue is making sure the metadata and the files are bound properly to the backend parameters. Here's how you can adjust the backend to correctly handle the file uploads and metadata:
MultipartFile Array: Spring's @RequestParam will map multiple files sent with the same name to a List.
Metadata Mapping: To map the document metadata (such as documentId and title), you can use a map or a custom DTO.
Here's the updated backend method:
 @PostMapping("/{documentEntityType}/{entityId}/documents")
    public ResponseEntity<UploadWithLockResultsDto> saveDocuments(
        @PathVariable("documentEntityType") DocumentEntityType documentEntityType,
        @PathVariable("entityId") Integer entityId,
        @RequestParam("documents") List<MultipartFile> documents,  // Receive the files
        @RequestParam Map<String, String> documentMetadata) throws AuthException, IOException {
    
        // Ensure the documents and metadata are mapped correctly
        List<DocumentInputDto> documentInputDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < documents.size(); i++) {
            MultipartFile file = documents.get(i);
    
            // Retrieve metadata for each document
            String documentId = documentMetadata.get("documents[" + i + "].documentId");
            String title = documentMetadata.get("documents[" + i + "].title");
    
            // Create DocumentInputDto from metadata and file
            DocumentInputDto documentInputDto = new DocumentInputDto();
            documentInputDto.setDocumentId(Long.parseLong(documentId));
            documentInputDto.setTitle(title);
            documentInputDto.setContent(file); // Assuming 'content' is a MultipartFile field in your DTO
    
            documentInputDtos.add(documentInputDto);
        }
    
        // Save the documents to the database (service call)
        var uploadWithLockResultsDto = documentService.updateDocuments(documentInputDtos, authentication.getName(), authentication.getPrincipal());
        return handleUploadWithLockResults(uploadWithLockResultsDto);
    }

Step 3: Ensure DocumentInputDto is Correct
Make sure that your DocumentInputDto class has a field for the MultipartFile and that you're using getters and setters correctly. Here's a simple version of the DocumentInputDto class:
public class DocumentInputDto {
    private Long documentId;
    private String title;
    private MultipartFile content; // The file being uploaded

    // Getters and setters
    public Long getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(Long documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public MultipartFile getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(MultipartFile content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}

Step 4: Handle Multipart Configuration (if needed)
Make sure your Spring Boot application is configured to handle multipart file uploads. This is typically done in the application.properties or application.yml file. Here's how you can configure it:
# application.properties
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

